# If T is a hermitian linear transformation, prove its inverse is hermitian?

Tags: linear-algebra

Knowing only that a hermitian linear transformation is one such that $(T(x),y) = (x,T(y))$, where $(x,y)$ denotes the inner product of x and y, how does one prove that $T^{-1}$ is hermitian? It seems like it should be a simple question but I haven't made any progress.
You can use matrices to represent linear transformations.

Comment: Of course you must assume $T^{-1}$ exists.

Answer (score 2):

$\langle T^{-1}(x),y\rangle=\langle T^{-1}(x),T(T^{-1}(y))\rangle=\langle T(T^{-1}(x)),T^{-1}(y)\rangle=\langle x,T^{-1}(y)\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $T^{-1} T = I$, we have $(T^{-1} T)^* = T^* (T^{-1})^* = I = T^* (T^*)^{-1}$. Premultiplying by $(T^*)^{-1}$ gives which $(T^{-1})^* = (T^*)^{-1}$ is true in general.

Using the fact that $T$ is Hermitian gives
$(T^{-1})^* = (T^*)^{-1} = T^{-1}$, hence $T^{-1}$ is Hermitian.